# "Device Descriptor" Error on waking up from suspend

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, wakeup

I'm currently struggling with my Kubuntu 18.04 system. When waking up the machine from `systemctl suspend`, the screen prints some lines of the following error:

```
[17823.756393] usb 8-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[17829.064673] usb 8-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[17829.300671] usb 8-1: device descriptor read/64, error -2
```

It adds some of those lines on every wake up.
Sometimes, the machine freezes and doesn't even load the login screen, so I need to reboot. I've googled the errors already, but cannot find any clue.

Hope someone has an idea and can help me.

Thank you guys!

EDIT: `sudo journalctl -f | grep usb` has following output:

```
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb usb8: root hub lost power or was reset
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb usb9: root hub lost power or was reset
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: device descriptor read/64, error -2
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: device descriptor read/64, error -2
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: device descriptor read/64, error -2
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: device descriptor read/64, error -2
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: device descriptor read/64, error -2
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: device descriptor read/64, error -2
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: device descriptor read/64, error -2
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC NetworkManager[950]: <info>  [1583583100.8166] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/net/wlx00c0ca975098, iface: wlx00c0ca975098)
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC NetworkManager[950]: <info>  [1583583100.8258] radio killswitch /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0 disappeared
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/usb8/8-1
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/0003:1A2C:4D7C.0001
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0
Mär 07 13:11:40 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271, bcdDevice= 1.08
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: Product: UB91C
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: SerialNumber: 12345
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1/0003:1A2C:4D7C.0002
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/usb8/8-1
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 4-2: new low-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a2c, idProduct=4d7c, bcdDevice= 1.10
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 4-2: Product: USB Keyboard
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 4-2: Manufacturer: SEMICO
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: input: SEMICO USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/0003:1A2C:4D7C.0004/input/input21
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: hid-generic 0003:1A2C:4D7C.0004: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [SEMICO USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input0
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: input: SEMICO USB Keyboard Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1/0003:1A2C:4D7C.0005/input/input22
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: usb 8-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC mtp-probe[9382]: checking bus 4, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2"
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: input: SEMICO USB Keyboard System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1/0003:1A2C:4D7C.0005/input/input23
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: input: SEMICO USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1/0003:1A2C:4D7C.0005/input/input25
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC kernel: hid-generic 0003:1A2C:4D7C.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [SEMICO USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input1
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1/0003:1A2C:4D7C.0005
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.1
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/0003:1A2C:4D7C.0004
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0
Mär 07 13:11:41 my-PC upowerd[1150]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-2
Mär 07 13:11:42 my-PC NetworkManager[950]: <info>  [1583583102.0934] rfkill1: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/ieee80211/phy1/rfkill1) (driver ath9k_htc)
Mär 07 13:11:42 my-PC NetworkManager[950]: <info>  [1583583102.1141] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/net/wlx00c0ca975098, iface: wlx00c0ca975098)
Mär 07 13:11:42 my-PC NetworkManager[950]: <info>  [1583583102.1141] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/net/wlx00c0ca975098, iface: wlx00c0ca975098): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mär 07 13:11:44 my-PC ModemManager[929]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/usb8/8-1': not supported by any plugin
```

Comment: what usb device have you plugged in? Or this appears without any usb devices connected

Comment: I've plugged some usb devices. Don't know how to print all connected devices.

Comment: lsusb could help

Comment: `sudo journalctl -f | grep usb`

Comment: In my case I have only this: `бер 06 18:55:52 lenovo kernel: usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
бер 06 18:55:52 lenovo kernel: usb 6-1: reset low-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
`

Comment: I've inserted a flashdrive to test, and also, my webcam is identified as usb device and I have an optical mouse

Comment: ```sudo journalctl -f | grep usb``` prints nothing.

Comment: it will show when you insert or remove your flashdrive or do whatever related. Leave this command working during closing/opening your laptop lid

Comment: @Gryu, I've added the output of ```journalctl``` to the question. That's waht is shown on wake up.